# Fatal error: Allowed memory size in PHP when allocating less

Tags: images

I am trying to upload several hundred images but I get this error:

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 12288 bytes) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/wp-includes/media.php on line 2751

I have set ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M'); and in php.ini (memory_limit = 1024M;)

How to detect what is wrong ?

Comment: Hello Andys,
Fatal error occurred because  you are trying to allocate more memory than you are allowed to use. There is a limit of RAM allocated to a host on server, and may be it is less than 1024MB for you. Start allocating memory from a small value like 64MB and keep testing by increasing 64MB if the memory works for you. You will get to know the memory limit by this method.

Comment: Thanks for reply but this is my local server MAMP and I can manage the size of ram ...

Comment: When I had an error like that it was my php version that need to be uptaded (was 5.2). Don't really think about a ram matter but more a function that is badly understood by the server (line 2751 is for the attachment taxonomy not for the upload).

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same error some time ago.

I don't know exactly what was wrong but after contacting our web hoster we could solve the issue. Something is wrong with your htacces file I guess.

Sory but can't make a comment since I don't have enoug reputation